# Java Jersey 2 client and proxies

Tags: java, rest, proxy, jersey, jersey-2.0

I use Jersey 2.11 to access the confluence REST API and get content from there.

```
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONArray;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;
import org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheClientProperties;
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientProperties;
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.authentication.HttpAuthenticationFeature;
import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
```

....

```
HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic(
    "confluenceUsername", "confluencePassword"
);

ClientConfig cc = new ClientConfig();
cc.property(ClientProperties.PROXY_URI, "xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx");
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(cc);

client.register(feature);

WebTarget target = client.target(credential.getUrl())
    .path("rest").path("api").path("content").path(id)
    .queryParam("expand", "space,body.storage,version,container,ancestors");

Response response = target.request().get();
```

Is this the current right way to use proxy in Java with Jersey 2.11 ? I get always an exception

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.Connect Exception: Connection refused: connect
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:229)
...
```

The confluence site which I want to access use https. On a machine which don't need a proxy it work with

```
HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic(
    "confluenceUsername", "confluencePassword");
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
client.register(feature);
```

so Confluence isn't the problem. I think that is something wrong with proxy spefication but don't know what.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2684496/2078908

Comment: @ursa do you mean that my proxy configuration is up-to-date with jersey 2.11 and the problem is the missing SSL certificate accepting?

Comment: yep. seems your client does not accept certificate from proxy, so I propose you to dig in this side.

Comment: I propose to use this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9541524/1791139 but the code is for old jersey 1 version, do you have any example for current 2.11 which accept all SSL certifcates?

Comment: @user1791139 see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942648/how-to-add-a-http-proxy-for-jersey2-client solution with apache connector

Answer (score 1):

I could not manage proxy in jersey client so i use the default client creation

```
HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic(
    "confluenceUsername", "confluencePassword");
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
client.register(feature);
```

and start my application with

```
java -Dhttps.proxyHost=xx.xx.xx.xx -Dhttps.proxyPort:xxxx -jar myApp.jar
```

If someone find out the correct solution to handle this with jersey 2.11 feel free to post an answer :)

Comment: yes - see the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942648/how-to-add-a-http-proxy-for-jersey2-client

Answer (score 0):

Can you please Try the following code .I use Jersey 2.0.1 and I am able to set the proxy setting into clientConfig object.and it's working

```
ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
config.connectorProvider(new ApacheConnectorProvider());
config.property(ClientProperties.PROXY_URI, "proxy_url");
config.property(ClientProperties.PROXY_USERNAME,"user_name");
config.property(ClientProperties.PROXY_PASSWORD,"password");
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
```