# caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, httpclient

I am using Spring Boot, Spring MVC and Spring Web with HttpClient. While trying to create **HttpClient** object in @Configuration class I get exception for following code:

```
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, hostnameVerifier);
    Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
            .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory())
            .register("https", sslSocketFactory)
            .build();
```

POM dependencies

```
<properties>
  <http.client>4.5.2</http.client>
  <http.core>4.4.4</http.core>
</<properties>
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>${http.core}</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>${http.client}</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Exception**:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.http.client.HttpClient]: Factory method 'getHttpClient' thr
ew exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<init>(Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLContext;Ljavax/net
/ssl/HostnameVerifier;)V                                                                                                                                      
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)                            
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)                          
        ... 155 more                                                                                                                                          
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<init>(Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLContext;Ljavax/net/ssl/HostnameVerifier;)
V                                                                                                                                                             
        at wsclient.RestClientConfig.getHttpClient(RestClientConfig.java:182)                                                         
        at wsclient.RestClientConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d3a9da1b.CGLIB$getHttpClient$2(<generated>)                              
        at wsclient.RestClientConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d3a9da1b$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a56984ae.invoke(<generated>)           
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)                                                                      
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)             
        at wsclient.RestClientConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d3a9da1b.getHttpClient(<generated>)                                      
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)                                                                                        
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)                                                                      
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)                                                              
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)                                                                                                   
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)                            
        ... 156 more
```

Any help or suggestions appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Remove the explicit `httpcore`dependency (it will be included with `httpclient`) and do `mvn clean install`. If the problem persists, show your complete POM as you might have a conflicting version of `httpclient` installed with something else.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried it but now I am getting exception
`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.ssl.TrustStrategy
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
        ... 49 more`

I checked other places, they suggested to use `<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    <version>4.4</version>
</dependency>` not working

Answer (score 3):

I was able to find the source of the library collision using this source:

***"That's odd, maybe it's loading the Apache classes from a different jar. Can you try running the following and pasting the output? It may give us a clue where it's trying to get those classes from:
org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()"***

Once I found the location, it turned out to be another jar file in my **/.m2/repository/** folder and then I cleaned up that folder so now it refers to the **/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.6/httpclient-4.5.6.jar** jar.

Original source: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/938

Answer (score 1):

I had faced similar kind of issue. An old httpClient jar was loaded first. After replacing that jar, it's working fine.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.(Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLContext;Ljavax/net/ssl/HostnameVerifier;)V
```

[image: error]